# similar jasper reporting tools for ios

Tags: pdf, ios, reporting

Are we able to find similar reporting tools for example like Java JasperReport for iOS?

We need a WYSIWYG visual editor to design the template, and then able to pass on data to template in order to generate the PDF? The most challenging here is that it must be done in offline, so we can't post the data to server and get back the PDF.

Commercial one is fine, it doesn't have to be free.